# Load and display images in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, tomahawk

I am saving the images into a folder of my system. These are uploaded successfully. and then i am saving the image name into the database. Now for displaying image i am getting the name of the file and then trying to display it but its not working. the code is as follows

For the Uploading purpose

```
<h:outputLabel value="Select Image"></h:outputLabel>
    <x:inputFileUpload id="file"
                       value="#{schoolMember.image}"
                       required="true" size="40" />
 <h:outputText></h:outputText>

<h:commandButton value="Save Details"
                  action="#{schoolMember.saveMember}">
</h:commandButton>
```

Method used in Java Class

```
public void saveMember()
    {
        File savedFileName;
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        String dirPath = "B:\\ImagesUpload\\";
        InputStream fileContent = null;
        try {
            fileContent = image.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String uploadFileName = trimFilePath(image.getName());
        String nameofFile=timeStamp + uploadFileName;
        this.setFileName(nameofFile);
        savedFileName = new File(dirPath +nameofFile);
        System.out.println(nameofFile);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(savedFileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        try {
            while ((len = fileContent.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        try {
            fileContent.close();
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        SchoolMemberDao dao=new SchoolMemberDao();
        dao.saveSchoolMember(this);
        this.clearAll();

    }
```

This all is working Fine, Now i am getting name of File from Database as given below

```
public void memberByEmailEdit() throws IOException
    {
        String dirPath = "B:\\ImagesUpload\\";
        SchoolMemberDao dao=new SchoolMemberDao();
        List<SchoolMember> list=dao.memberByEmail(memberEmail);
        this.memberId=list.get(0).memberId;

        this.fileName=list.get(0).fileName;


        String uploadFileName = trimFilePath(list.get(0).fileName);
        System.out.println(uploadFileName);
        this.setImageFileName(uploadFileName);

        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/faces/views/SchoolMembers/Principal/editProfile.xhtml"); 

    }
```

the method where i am getting these values using Query is

```
public List<SchoolMember> memberByEmail(String mEmail)
    {
        Transaction trans=null;
        Session session=HiberUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try{
            trans=session.beginTransaction();
            String queryString="from SchoolMember s where s.memberEmail = :id and memberType = 'principal'";
            Query query=session.createQuery(queryString);
            query.setString("id", mEmail);

            List<SchoolMember> list=query.list();
            if(list.size()>0)
            {
                return list;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now here as given below i am giving the url  to get the image but it is not displaying that image

```
<h:graphicImage height="100"
                width="100"
                url="B:\\ImagesUpload\\#{schoolMember.imageFileName}">
</h:graphicImage>
```

Comment: Try value instead of url

Comment: Not working... Not displaying anything

Comment: What do you mean its file name, Isn't web page show un-targeted image block?

Comment: Actually i am saving each file name by concatenating it with time date in database so that each file name will be unique and image file in a folder of my system. To get that i am getting the name of file from database into object imageFileName then i am giving the folder location and at last the imageFileName in url.

Comment: How you are saving/renaming your image, obviously with java, but you cannot load your system directories into web application. Because it is deployed on server.

Comment: Ok...But because of the Project Size will be increased. Isn't there any way to we can do it from the outside of the project?

Comment: You can store it in data server using FTP, through JAVA. When you are loading file first download it in web app and delete it afterwards.

Comment: You can store image in DB and use servlet in your web app for displaying it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Web application is deployed on server. Application only known to its own resources. Upload images into web app folder instead of B:/ImagesUpload like: `resouces/images/` than trying this

Web server is looking imagefile in like: `http://localhost:8080/B:/UploadedImages/xxx.jpg`, of-course it cant be done.
[Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-graphicimage-example/)

Comment: I need to take it out of my Application.So if there is any other way to do that.Please tell me

Comment: Use FTP from java, something like your upload!